# optimize for loop using for_each standard or boost tools

Tags: c++, boost

I try to optimize for loop below. It do a for loop over std::vector of a struct type. then it checks if any member with type equal to "INSIDE_WITH_MORE_ONE_INTER". if it found such member, it apply a function on it and finally based on the result it may keep the type of change it to "NOT_DEFINED".

```
for(pnt_vec_iter pnt_iter = newpnTs.begin(); pnt_iter != newpnTs.end(); pnt_iter++)
  {
    if(pnt_iter->_type == INSIDE_WITH_MORE_ONE_INTER)
    {
      if(!DoublePointsOnEdgeCheck(*this, pnt_iter->_face, pnt_iter))
      {
        pnt_iter->_type == NOT_DEFINED;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to optimize above code **excluding** **defining a function** to do so.

Comment: What makes you think you need to optimize the method in the first place?

Comment: First rule of optimization: **MEASURE**. What did your measurements say? How did that compare to your criterion of acceptable/not?

Comment: Micro-optimization: use ++pnt_iter

Comment: Are you sure `DoublePointsOnEdgeCheck` needs both `pnt_iter->_face` and `pnt_iter` arguments? Probably `pnt_iter` is enough.

Comment: You may also have a look at [GotW #2](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects) (doesn't really answer your question, but gives you some hints).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends way too much on context, like

- what's the locality of reference on data dependencies from DoublePointsOnEdgeCheck?
- what's the relative frequency of points with `_type==ISIDE_WITH_MORE_ONE_INTER`? How are the points ordered?
- What is the memory layout of a point? etc.

> #### Just profile it, and /imagine/ what would make the algorithm zip quicker through the set.

E.g.

- "What if I didn't have to loop through all the points?"
- "What if points were already indexed/sorted by `_type`?" (*you'd use a simple `equal_range(INSIDE_WITH_MORE_ONE_INTER)` call to reduce the work*)
- What if I **do not** do the work at all, but instead lazily re-evaluate the value for `_type` in an accessor `type()`?" (*Or does this break constness too much? Threading?*)

Etc.